# IntelliJ - Maven build with OSGi - workspace setup

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi

I'm facing the problem with setting up a development environment with Maven and OSGi dependencies in Intellij.

At the beginning, a few words about how it looks like. 
Everything is built on top of the Maven build. The whole hierarchy is already set up and I don't have any problems with building the project. It consists of many small submodules:

```
<modules>
    <module>com.modulea</module>
    <module>com.moduleb</module>
<modules>
```

Those modules use OSGi internally so everything might be presented with the following tree:

```
PARENT (pom.xml)
|----- Module A (pom.xml)
    |----- META-INF
        |----- MANIFEST.MF
            |----- Export-bundle: com.modulea

|----- Module B (pom.xml)
    |----- META-INF
        |----- MANIFEST.MF
            |----- Require-bundle: com.modulea
    |----- src
        ...
        |----- ModuleAClass (uses classes from com.modulea bundle)
```

The problem is connected with importing the project into IntelliJ. I imported it as a Maven project with checkboxes selected:

1. Create IntelliJ IDEA modules for aggregator projects (with 'pom' packaging)
2. Create module groups for multi-module Maven projects

IntelliJ created project's submodules basing on maven configurations but...
dependencies of those modules are set to libraries (Maven p2.eclipse-plugin). Is there any way to force it to use project's submodules? Of course, it is possible to do it manually (Project Settings -> Dependencies -> + -> Module dependency) but there are too many dependencies and submodules to repeat it every now and then again.

Additionally, if I have dependencies configured (library dependencies), OSMORC plugin is not able to resolve OSGi dependencies/configuration. For each of classes from an external bundle I got a message:

> The package 'com.modulea' is not imported in the manifest less... (Ctrl+F1)

Comment: To be honest? Really trying to build an OSGi app in IntelliJ ? Why not using Eclipse for such things which itself is based on OSGi and has support for OSGi things like target Plattform etc. ?

Comment: Well, I use Eclipse on a daily basis. I just assumed that if I have a working Maven build then it should be possible to setup a workspace in any IDE. Especially, when there is an OSGi plugin for IntelliJ.